# Show work order if it is not null in TimeSheetEntry

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I am creating an *visualforce* e-mail template on **TimeSheetEntry**:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Time Sheet Entry has been updated" recipientType="User" relatedToType="TimeSheetEntry">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
Hi,

Time Sheet Entry Data has been modified.

Details of the Time Sheet Entry.

Time Sheet Entry Number: {!relatedTo.TimeSheetEntryNumber}
Modified Date : {!relatedTo.LastModifiedDate}
Start Time : {!relatedTo.StartTime}
End Time :  {!relatedTo.EndTime}
Status :  {!relatedTo.Status}
Subject : {!relatedTo.Subject}
{IF( NOT(NULL(!relatedTo.WorkOrder) ) : {!relatedTo.WorkOrder.Subject}, )}



Thank you!
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

I need to show **Work Order** only in case it is not null.

But above e-mail is showing like below output:

[image]

How can I hide the **Work Order** when it is null?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apex:outPutpanel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm) as below to conditionally show elements in visualforce email template:-

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND(relatedTo.WorkOrderId !='', relatedTo.WorkOrderId !=null)}">
       {!relatedTo.WorkOrder.Subject}
</apex:outputPanel>
```